# How do I display the images inline?

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, containers

I have the following code:

```
<div class="container">
<div style="float: right; width: 50%;"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/idleslidegloves/"> <img class="alignleft" src="http://idleslidegloves.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/instagram-22.png" alt="" /></a></div>
<div style="float: right; width: 60%;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/idleslidegloves/"><img class="alignright" src="http://idleslidegloves.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/facebook-7-22.png" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
```

On the page it gets displayed like this:

[This is how it gets displayed on my site.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jQha.png)

What can I do to make the images appear next to one another and not interfere with the text that is a div=wrap.

Code can be seen here in [idleslidegloves.com](http://idleslidegloves.com)

Any idea on how to fix this is welcomed.

Comment: Part of the problem might be that your total percentage is 110%.

Comment: [Is this what you were going for?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YdVoz.png)

Comment: [Get rid of those two divs, then replace the `<h3>` with this](https://gist.github.com/Tiny-Giant/be3d73b2403c9123036a)

Comment: @RandomLogic the part with Subscribe is not from same code, is coded within the plugin. So I cannot touch the text since there is no such text see this code here: https://gist.github.com/highacid/ac8471bfd23565ec7dc0

Comment: [Replace the `.container` div with this](https://gist.github.com/Tiny-Giant/7ea80341ddd43a8aa49b)

Comment: If that works for you, [here is what I would recommend as your question](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Tiny-Giant/0dc81e0c1e45820fbefc/raw/ac974af1f9d1c507e2d092db6b2d5b42210a0a77/34883302.md)

Comment: @RandomLogic it works, thanks a lot! Right now I do not have rights to edit this.

Comment: You can always [edit] your own posts.

Comment: @RandomLogic Yes but it tells me I need more points to edit them with more images...